# A convergent series of irrational numbers only which is not absolutely convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

While solving another problem I stumbled upon this. I wonder if such a series exists:
"a convergent series of **irrational numbers only** which is not absolutely convergent".
I am thinking but I cannot yet find a good (i.e. simple) example.
Could anyone provide such an example? The simpler, the better.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n\sqrt{2}}$$ this may be the series that you are looking for it has all irratiaonal

Comment: Actually, take $n=2$ and the term is rational

Comment: @vrugtehagel Not if they meant $n\sqrt{2}$. It's impossible to tell with the given notation that doesn't have the upper bar on the root symbol.

Comment: sorry for the appearance of my solution but root  is just over 2 and the $n$ stays outside